# Simplest way to add a thumb size to a model using Paperclip in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a Rails model that uses Paperclip and has many thumb sizes. I would like to add a new thumb size and generate ONLY that size if possible - it it completely unnecessary to regenerate all of the old thumbs again. Something like Photo.find(123).photo.reprocess!(:new_size) would be perfect but unfortunately doesn't exist. Anyone know a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The thumb-size can be set in the model of your pictures (see [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

As far as I remember it should be possible to regenerate by deleting the old thumbnails. However, there's also a rake-task for it:

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=YourModelName
```

Comment: The thing is, I happen to be storing my Paperclip photos on S3, so to regenerate all thumbnails is a huge waste of requests and time. Ideally, I'd like to push up only the new size.

Comment: Well, you could run your Rails-app locally, re-generate all thumbs and push them to S3 afterwards.

Comment: Try to change only the style-parameter, it should re-generate the thumbs on request then. I'm not sure about it, though.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is in the rake task

paperclip:refresh:missing_styles